# How do I insert some text where the cursor is?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I'm upgrading some Javascript which works on IE. However, I'm having some problems.

Heres the IE code:

```
var range = document.getElementById('text').contentWindow.window
                 .document.getElementById('Content').createTextRange();
var textObj = document.getElementById('text').contentWindow.window
                 .document.getElementById('Content');

var textFieldValue = theSmile;
if (range && textObj.CursorPos) {
    var CursorPos = textObj.CursorPos;
    CursorPos.text = CursorPos.text.charAt(CursorPos.text.length - 1) 
                              == ' ' ?' ' + textFieldValue : textFieldValue;
} else {
  textObj.value  = textFieldValue;
}
```

I've tried replacing `CreateTextRange` with `CreateRange` for non-IE browsers, but this doesn't help. With code like this:

```
var range;
var textObj;
var iframeEl = document.getElementById('text');
if (iframeEl.contentDocument) { // DOM
    range = iframeEl.contentDocument.getElementById('Content').createRange;
    textObj= iframeEl.contentDocument.getElementById('Content');
} else if (iframeEl.contentWindow) { // IE win
    range = iframeEl.contentWindow.document.getElementById('Content')
                                                            .createTextRange;
    textObj= iframeEl.contentWindow.document.getElementById('Content');
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a function to insert text at the cursor in a textarea or text input, which is what it seems you have. It works in all major browsers:

```
function insertTextAtCursor(el, text) {
    var val = el.value, endIndex, range, doc = el.ownerDocument;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number"
            && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
        endIndex = el.selectionEnd;
        el.value = val.slice(0, endIndex) + text + val.slice(endIndex);
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = endIndex + text.length;
    } else if (doc.selection != "undefined" && doc.selection.createRange) {
        el.focus();
        range = doc.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.text = text;
        range.select();
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
var iframeWin = document.getElementById('text').contentWindow;
var textObj = iframeWin.document.getElementById('Content');

insertTextAtCursor(textObj, "foo");
```